# A finite dimensional normed space

Tags: functional-analysis

I would like to find a short proof for the following theorems:

Theorem 1. *A normed space is finite dimensional iff all of its linear functional is continuous.*

Theorem 2. *A normed space is finite dimensional iff its unit ball is compact.*

Thank you in advance.

Comment: First, do you see why the conditions are necessary? Which tools do you want to be used?

Comment: @Davide Giraudo: Dear Sir. One of the direction in both theorems is easy to prove. How to prove that the given space is finite dimensional. I would like to use the simplest tool.

Comment: For the first theorem, I know a proof which uses Zorn lemma to get a Hamel basis. Then with that, we can construct a non-continuous linear functional.

Comment: @Davide Giraudo: Dear Sir. Hamel basis is not familiar with me. Can you use a simpler tool? Thank you for your helping.

Comment: @blindman, A hamel basis is simply the "usual" basis that you're familiar with: a linearly independent set such that every vector in the space can be written as a finite linear combination of elements from that set.

Comment: Maybe the shortest proof isnt so easy to understand.

Comment: I wouldn't expect "short proofs" of those facts. One is deceived by the way they are written, because they only talk about finite-dimensional spaces. But the two assertions say exactly this:

 1. A normed space is infinite-dimensioan if and only if it has a non-continuous linear functional.
 2. A normed space is infinite-dimensional if and only if its unit ball is not compact.

Usual proofs are of the form "finite-dimensional implies continuous linear functional and compact unit ball", and "infinite-dimensional implies a discontinuous linear functional and non-compact unit ball".

Comment: Ok. For the second theorem take a look on the page 160 of "Brezis - Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and PDE". For the first one is like Davide Giraudo said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direction you asked for in the comments:

Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional normed space.

1. Pick a countable independent collection $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, pick $(y_i)_i$ such that $(e_n,y_i)_{n,i}$ is a basis. Let $f$ be the functional determined by $f(e_n)=n\|e_n\|$ and $f(y_i)=0$. Then $f$ is unbounded.
2. By [Riesz's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27_lemma) one easily constructs a sequence of independent vectors in the unit ball without a converging subsequence.